# bash script replace all null values in a file by lines from another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two files:

```
File1.sql
```

here is the few first lines:

```
insert into comment (id, field1, field2, field3, date) values (8001, 13, 44, null, '2007-07-06 02:48:15');
insert into comment (id, field1, field2, field3, date) values (8002, 18, 738, null, '2008-12-23 16:30:17');
insert into comment (id, field1, field2, field3, date) values (8003, 3, 150, null, '2007-06-07 06:27:52');
```

and another `file2.txt`:

```
'this is test'
'another example'
'third one'
```

they both have the same number of lines.
I want to replace **null** string in `file1.sql`, we have only one **null** in each line, with the corresponding line from the other `file2.txt`

How can I do it in `sed` or `awk`?

### update

```
OLD="null"
NEW="abc"

sed -i 's/$OLD/$NEW/g' file.txt
```

this is my try, but very basic and cannot go further.

Comment: `How can I do it in a one-liner?` you do it by trying it out yourself and if that command doesn't work, then we can help...

Comment: well, `awk` is better suited in this case... and the `sed` you tried won't work for the simple example as you need double quotes for variable substitution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk, pretty much complete rewrite as `&` in `a[FNR]` when using `sub` causes problems.

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR { a[FNR]=$0; next }        # hash the records to a
{ 
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                 # iterate every field
    if(tolower($i)~/^null,?$/) {   # if its null (or null,)
        $i=a[FNR]($i~/,$/?",":"")  # replace it
        break                      # only once 
    }
}1' file2.txt File1.sql
insert into comment (id, field1, field2, field3, date) values (8001, 13, 44, 'this is test', '2007-07-06 02:48:15');
insert into comment (id, field1, field2, field3, date) values (8002, 18, 738, 'another example', '2008-12-23 16:30:17');
insert into comment (id, field1, field2, field3, date) values (8003, 3, 150, 'third one', '2007-06-07 06:27:52');
```

Comment: @EdMorton Fixed. I guess there really is no foolproof way to handle the & using `sub`?